# Append price with jQuery based on content in table

Tags: jquery

The div's labelled "simple-product-tile" contain default prices which need overriding with the prices further down the page in a comparison table **if** the name of the product is the same.

I've got some code which is succesfully compairing each product title to the table further down the page and pulling the associated price for a console output.

I now want to extend this logic so it overrides the original HTML markup in span.lbl-price.

I assumed it would be as simple as adding:

```
$(".lbl-price").append(associatedPrice);
```

However this results in each price being added to each element three times.

This isnt the case in console where it successfully logs the correct price once:

[image]

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5vtydcb7/15/

```js
$(function() {
  //Find each title
  $("#relatedProductsTab1 .simple-product-tile a.product-title").each(function() {
    //Make this text a variable
    var relatedProd = $(this).text();
    //log the variable
    console.log(relatedProd);
    //If this variable exist in the list...
    if ($("table.waffle td:contains(" + relatedProd + ")").length) {
      //Log to console
      console.log('Related product is located in imported data');
      //Pull price data from next table cell
      var associatedPrice = $("table.waffle td:contains(" + relatedProd + ")").next('td').text();
      //Log price
      console.log(associatedPrice);
      //Override related product price with this variable
      //$(".lbl-price").append(associatedPrice);
    } else {
      console.log('Related product is NOT located in imported data');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='relatedProductsTab1'>
  <div class="simple-product-tile">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="product-title" href="#">Foo First Widget</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="lbl-price">£10.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="simple-product-tile">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="product-title" href="#">My Second Foo Widget</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="lbl-price">£10.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="simple-product-tile">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="product-title" href="#">My Third Foo Widget</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="lbl-price">£10.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<table class="waffle">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>Comparison Table</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Foo First Widget</td>
    <td>£9.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>My Second Foo Widget</td>
    <td>£10.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>My Third Foo Widget</td>
    <td>11.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target `lbl-price` with respect of current element. Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target common ancestor then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target desired element.

```
 $(this)
   .closest('.simple-product-tile') //Target common ancestor 
   .find(".lbl-price") //Target the lbl
   .append(associatedPrice);
```

```js
$(function() {
  //Find each title
  $("#relatedProductsTab1 .simple-product-tile a.product-title").each(function() {
    //Make this text a variable
    var relatedProd = $(this).text();
    //log the variable
    console.log(relatedProd);
    //If this variable exist in the list...
    if ($("table.waffle td:contains(" + relatedProd + ")").length) {
      //Log to console
      console.log('Related product is located in imported data');
      //Pull price data from next table cell
      var associatedPrice = $("table.waffle td:contains(" + relatedProd + ")").next('td').text();
      //Log price
      console.log(associatedPrice);
      //Override related product price with this variable
      $(this)
        .closest('.simple-product-tile')
        .find(".lbl-price")
        .append(associatedPrice);
    } else {
      console.log('Related product is NOT located in imported data');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='relatedProductsTab1'>
  <div class="simple-product-tile">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="product-title" href="#">Foo First Widget</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="lbl-price">£10.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="simple-product-tile">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="product-title" href="#">My Second Foo Widget</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="lbl-price">£10.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="simple-product-tile">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="product-title" href="#">My Third Foo Widget</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="lbl-price">£10.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<table class="waffle">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>Comparison Table</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Foo First Widget</td>
    <td>£9.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>My Second Foo Widget</td>
    <td>£10.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>My Third Foo Widget</td>
    <td>11.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yup thats the one, great. I just needed to be more specific with my selector.